# Use of SendGrid Mail with Configuration in ASP.Net Core Razor on Azure site

Tags: c#, configuration, azure-web-app-service, sendgrid, razor-pages

I am working through this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/accconfirm?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=aspnetcore2x).
In it I have set up `SendGrid` and included the credentials using the `Secret Manager` tool.  Per the tutorial I have created a `AuthMessageSenderOptions` class added a statement in `Startup.cs` `ConfigureServices`:

```
services.Configure<AuthMessageSenderOptions>(Configuration);
```

This works fine in the development environment. When I move the application to the Azure site I have set up the same values in the Application Settings like:

[image: Image of Environment Settings in Azure]

In the tutorial it states that:

> If you publish the app to Azure, you can set the SendGrid secrets as application settings in the Azure Web App portal. The configuration system is set up to read keys from environment variables.

This seems to imply that I do not need to change my code to run on the Azure site but it is not working.
Can anyone give me any insight?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved this problem so there is no need for more help.

In case anyone is curious, I needed to solve some unrelated issues with how VisualStudio was publishing the site to Azure.  Once those were fixed it started working.

The lesson here is that one can use the Secret Manager to store the SendGrid credentials during development and then put the same key-value pairs in the Application Settings on the Azure site.

Incidentally, it appears to me that SendGrid only needs the SendGridKey value.  It doesn't appear to use the SendGridUser value.  I haven't tested this,, however.